# Issues with recursion when using Merge Sort to count inversion in Java

Tags: java, recursion

This code is for problem where there is a file with 100000 integers, each on a line, which is supposed to be 100000 ordered integers in an array. The goal is to count the number of inversions (when a number to the right on the array is larger than a number on the left). The implementation is supposed to use merge sort. When merging a left and right subarray, if there are still values remaining in the left subarray when a value from the right subarray is used for the merge, the number of values remaining in the left subarray is incremented to the total inversion count.

My code does not return the correct number of inversions for simple cases, so I think the issue in my code is in the recursion, or the three lines

```
mergeSort(left);
mergeSort(right);
merge(ii, left, right);
```

I cannot figure out the reason I am not getting the correct number of inversions. Most likely it is because I should be incrementing inversions more when mergesorting the left and right subarrays, but I have not figured out the error yet.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Inversion {

    public static int inversions = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int[] list = new int[100000];
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("src/inversion.txt"));
        for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            list[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println(inversions);

        sc.close();
    }
    public static void mergeSort(int[] ii)
    {
        if (ii.length > 1)
        {
        int[]left = Arrays.copyOfRange(ii,  0,  ii.length/2);
        int[]right = Arrays.copyOfRange(ii, ii.length/2, ii.length);

        mergeSort(left);
        mergeSort(right);
        merge(ii, left, right);
        }

    }
    public static void merge(int[]result, int[]left, int[]right)
    {
        int ileft=0;
        int iright=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
        {
            if (iright>=right.length || (ileft < left.length && left[ileft] <= right[iright]))
            {
                result[i]=left[ileft++];
            }
            else
            {
                result[i]=right[iright++];
                inversions += left.length-ileft;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `public static void mergeSort(int[] ii)` method in `if (ii.length > 1)` you should be checking if `ii.length >= 2` because the merge sort algorithm splits the array in half which is why you divide by 2 in `Arrays.copyOfRange`. 1 can not be split into a whole number when divided in half.

In merge try `left[ileft] < right[iright]` instead of `left[ileft] <= right[iright]`